# augmented reality orientation

Tags: android, augmented-reality

hello i want to ask which sensor is the best to find your current orientation? the orientation sensor or the combination of [accelerometer](/questions/tagged/accelerometer) and [magnometer](/questions/tagged/magnometer) (compass). I have seen a lot of augmented reality versions and i wonder which one is the best! Some of these use the [orientation](/questions/tagged/orientation) to find the azimuth whereas other use the accelerometer and magnometer. As i know orientation sensor is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you need framework that is free [MIXARE](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/) is really great

Comment: thanks for your fast answer but i need to make my application from scratch and mixare is a little bit complex to understand the way it uses the orientation!

Comment: I changed quite a few things in mixare to get it to work as I wanted. All classes are there all you need to do is dig in :) Basically it detects available sensors and uses ones available since it does work on older mobile devices as well as new ones

Comment: i have already used mixare framework and it is actually a very good framework. I can also make changes to it but i want to create an ar app from scratch for my thesis and not use an already built one!

Answer (score 2):

You can use gyroscope sensor to find the rotation vector. It can be used to get the azimuth.

```
SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager)
getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
rSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
```

And in onSensorChanged function,

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix, event.values);
SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mValues);

azimuth = Math.toDegrees(mValues[0]));
```

But in some devices this sensor may not be available. In that case you can use combination of Accelerometer and Magnetometer.

```
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
aSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

In onSensorChaged function,

```
switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
        magnetic = event.values.clone();
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        accelerometer = event.values.clone();
        break;
}

if (magnetic != null && accelerometer != null) {
    Rot = new float[9];
    I = new float[9];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rot, I, accelerometer, magnetic);

    float[] outR = new float[9];
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(Rot, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
            SensorManager.AXIS_Z, outR);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, values);

    azimuth = values[0];
    magnetic = null;
    accelerometer = null;
}
```

Gyroscope provides the best result out of the two options.